# How to make Swagger pass the correct parameters?

Tags: c#, api, rest, .net-core, swagger

I have a .net core API call that will takes parameters; a string, two dates and an integer. Here's the url format when hosting it locally:

```
 https://localhost/api/v2/TimeSeries/<id>/<from-date>/<to-date>/<int-value>
```

The controller is defined as follows:

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}/{from:datetime}/{to:datetime}/{resolution:int}")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2")]
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync([FromRoute] Query query) 
                                      => Ok(await _mediator.Send(query));
```

This works as intended - at least when called from [Postman](https://www.postman.com). My problem is with the test-functionality in Swagger: For some reason it does not generate a valid url for the endpoint. It *looks* correct when considering only the description and parameters:

[image: Postman parameters]

The URL that is called when clicking *Execute* however, is not formatted correctly; instead of including the provided parameters it uses their names, with curly brackets and all, resulting in a 404 error:

[image: Incorrect postman result]

As stated, the call itself works. I can call it and get the expected response using Postman, so I'm confused as to why Swagger can't handle this correctly.

Comment: try to match the naming of parameters from query object to controller url, not Id -> id

Comment: Swagger UI request issue is caused by parameter letter case mismatch - the URL uses lowercase param names (`id`, `from`, etc.) but the parameter definitions have an uppercase first letter (`Id`, `From`, etc.). You could either change the request URL to match, or review the annotations in case they affect the param name letter case.

Answer (score 0):

create a class like model class for your parameters

```
public class Parameters{

publuc string id {get;set;}

  public DateTime? from{ get; set; }
  public DateTime? to { get; set; }

  public int resolution {get;set;}

}
```

and pass it on your controller like this

```
[HttpGet("/xyz")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2")]
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync([FromQuery] Parameters query) 
                                      => Ok(await _mediator.Send(query));
```